# Unable to read response when Subprocess shell=False

Tags: python, subprocess

In below code if execute in windows platform i am getting output

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = " Application.exe arg1 arg2"
process = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

while process.poll() is None:
 output = process.stdout.readline()
 print output,
```

Output> Some text

But if i use `shell=False` I am not getting output how to get response in this case .

Comment: as I said yeasterday: you don't need `process.poll()` here. Use [this code instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Answer (score 2):

When you set `shell=False`, you must provide `COMMAND` as list containing program name and arguments:

With `shell=True`:

```
COMMAND = "Application.exe arg1 arg2"
```

With `shell=False`:

```
COMMAND = ["Application.exe", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

I would recommend you to avoid using `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` in any case for security measures and use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead whenever possible:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> COMMAND = " Application.exe arg1 arg2".strip().split()
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

>>> output, error = process.communicate()
>>> print output
```

Comment: On Windows, you can pass the command as a string (it is a native interface). The issue might be the leading space in the command.